# Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin Error on install required python library remotior_sensus

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, error, landsat, plugins

I have been trying to install the semi - automatic classification plugin but it results with the following error:

> semi automatic classification plugin : Error, please install the
> Python required library remotior_sensus

I tried reinstalling stable version of qgis 3.28.11 but still doesn't work out.

How do I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to install `remotior_sensus`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually i am using a tool called 3Di which is powered by QGIS. It seems that semi automatic classfication plugin is working in 3Di but when i try to create another profile using QGIS , i am recieving another error calling its classFactory() method.

Answer (score 0):

Open OSGeo Shell and run command `pip3 install --upgrade remotior-sensus scikit-learn torch`